# Changing an image container to 1170px from 970px in Shopify

Tags: css, responsive-design, shopify

I have a purchased a Shopify theme 'Testament' which supports 1170px - the original PSD's were design & supplied at 970px, but after further review, the client wants the main image container stretch to 1170px.

Can anyone give me directions on how to do this myself? The developer is trying to make me pay extra thousands $ for this update, but I understand this to be a reasonably straight-forward task, especially since the purchase theme already included this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the CSS/HTML that controls the images you are dealing with. StackOverflow is a place to ask specific code based questions. This is a method question currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that by adding the media query in your custom.css.liquid of the testament theme.

```
/* !Rows, Widest to Thinest */  
@media screen and (min-width: 1220px) {
  .gridlock .row { width: 1170px; }
}
```

and it'll render the width:1170px on the screens wider than 1220px.